# How to fix transliteration?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a transliterator, to be frank, trying to translate an already transliterated word into Russian. 
Here is the code I'm trying to fix

```
if (Regex.Match (inputtedText, @ "^ [A-Za-z] + $"). Success)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j <length; j ++)
                 {
                     inputtedText = inputtedText.Replace (lat[j], rus[j]);
                     inputtedText = inputtedText.Replace (lat[j].ToLower(), rus[j].ToLower());
                 }
             }
return inputtedText;
```

Everything is be fine, but there's one thing: there are values which length is more than one character in the dictionary (where the alphabet and it's transliterated version is placed) ("ш" - "sh", "ж" - "zh", etc.), and the program recognizes only one character (so, the word with the letter "sh" is converted into the word with the letters "c" and "h"). 
I understood I need to replace several elements in inputtedText with one, but I do not realize how. A regular expression here is only for entering Latin characters.
What can I do?

Comment: Order your lat and rus collections in a way that the longer latin transliteration char sequences come first (basically sort by length of latin char sequences); so your loop replaces the longer sequences such as "zh" first before then later trying to replace any shorter sequences/single characters like "z" and "h" left in the input string.

Comment: Also make sure you use actual real kyrillic letters and not latin look-alikes like the latin "c" for the kyrillic "с" (like i just did here in my comment ;-) ). Or pay utmost attention to the ordering of the elements in the lat/rus collections. Otherwise you might get into situations like where your loop replaces the latin "s" with "c" (using latin character "c" as substitute for kyrillic "с"), which it then in a later iteration might try to replace again from "c" to kyrillic ??? (i mean, come to think of it, what kyrillic character would you replace the latin "c" with?

Comment: @elgonzo
Thank you a lot!!! :) You made my day.